# INDEX, MATCH - MATCH Error on multiple documents

Tags: excel

I'm having an issue when I use Index and Match.

I'm trying to compare to last years YTD data.

*Doc 1 (New doc) - Doc 2 (Old Doc)*

On *Doc 2*, Sheet1 where I have the Index, Match function with a date selected on A1:

```
=INDEX('Sheet3'!D22:DU22,MATCH(A1,Table25[[#Headers],[4/24/2015]:[10/31/2015]],0))
```

It works successfully and returns the data.

I have set cell `"L48"` as `"10/25/2015"` formatted as date on *Doc 1*.
When I use the same function on *Doc 2* and reference the document *Doc 1* I get a N/A:

```
=INDEX('2015 FINAL.xlsm]Sheet3'!$D$22:$DU$22,MATCH(L48,' 2015 FINAL.xlsm'!Table25[[#Headers],[4/24/2015]:[10/31/2015]],0))
```

For fun, I tried "10/31/2015" as the Match lookup on Doc 1:

```
=INDEX('2015 FINAL.xlsm]Sheet3'!$D$22:$DU$22,MATCH("10/25/2015",'2015 FINAL.xlsm'!Table25[[#Headers],[4/24/2015]:[10/31/2015]],0))
```

This worked successfully. What's going on here? On L48 I have `"10/25/2015"` formatted by date but I get an error. When I typed it in the direct date it works?

I'm hoping to type a date of my choice on *L48* and it will work just like the first formula listed.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you double check your `L48` is formatted as correct date type? Or try to use Format Painter from `A1` to `L48`.

Comment: Yes, "L48" is correctly formatted as a date.

Answer (score 0):

When referencing the other workbook either use:

1) Both brackets and no quotes, `[2015 FINAL.xlsm]Sheet3!`. This means the workbook needs to be open to update the values.

2) Use the full path`'C;\Documents\2015 FINAL.xlsm]Sheet3!'` which allow reference to a closed book.

See [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-c98d1803-dd75-4668-ac6a-d7cca2a9b95f) as reference.